# Unable to get scn timestamp in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

`Scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn)` function gives me unsupported network data type or representation error but `ora_rowscn` giving change number

Comment: What is the full error you get, including the ORA- error number if there is one; and if not, which client is giving you the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have (I presume):

```
SQL> select scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn) from dept where rownum = 1;
select scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn) from dept where rownum = 1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08181: specified number is not a valid system change number
ORA-06512: at "SYS.SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP", line 1
```

Does `ora_rowscn` exists? You said it does; and you're right:

```
SQL> select ora_rowscn from dept where rownum = 1;

ORA_ROWSCN
----------
1,6598E+13

SQL>
```

What happened, then? It's because of the [SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions161.htm#SQLRF06325) note:

> (...) The time for the association to become obsolete elapses only when the database is open. An error is returned if the SCN specified for the argument to SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP is **too old**.

So, what happens if it isn't that old (how? Create a new table, for example):

```
SQL> create table test as select * from dept;

Table created.

SQL> select scn_to_timestamp(ora_rowscn) from test where rownum = 1;

SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
06.04.22 10:32:43,000000000

SQL>
```

Right, now it works.